# What is happening to my programs and session?

Tags: gnome-session

In the last 2 days, when I am away from my computer for a while and come back, I enter my password and it comes up, but I can't do anything.   It has always been that when I come back, my browser is still open and any other programs I left running, but now nothing, just the desktop.  And when I select "activities" it shows nothing there.   And if I try to start the terminal or my browser, they don't start.   I have to log out, and log back in and then sometimes that doesn't work.
Also, if I right click on the desktop and select 'settings' or 'display settings' that won't start up.  There is just a number "2" that appears in a box on the upper left side.
Did I mistakenly set some setting for it to act this way?   How do I get it to just start back up the way it used to, with the session I was in previously?
Thanks

Comment: "*number "2" that appears in a box on the upper left side*" suggests that you have more than one monitor plugged in. Maybe your activity is happening on monitor #1. Check Settings --> Displays

Comment: I'll try checking the display settings next time I restart the computer.   Now, as I mentioned, if I try to enter the settings or display settings nothing comes up except that number 2, no settings window.

Comment: I just tried to start Skype.  The icon comes up but you can't open it up to use it.

Comment: Yea, I restarted the computer and settings will not come up.  And other programs are iffy.  Skype won't come up and my regular Firefox won't start up.   That is, if I try to click on the icon, it says it is starting, but never comes up.  I tried right clicking on the icon and telling it to open a new window.  It doesn't restore my previous session, but at least I get a window.   But Skype won't come up., no way to open up a window.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  All this time I have had my monitor hooked up to both the VGA and the HDMI.   I changed the "display settings" (I don't remember, but I think I put it onto single) and it messed up.   Before I turned it on this AM, I unplugged the VGA cable and now it looks like it all works again, skype came up and I can get into the settings.  BVut that does look like a glitch to me if you have VGA and HDMI hooked up to one monitor and I think I had changed it to display only on a single monitor, hat seems to cancel out some things, like getting into settings and also skype.

Comment: Your system does not know that Monitor #1 and Monitor #2 are the same hardware. It cannot see your monitor. It only knows that two monitors are plugged in and responding. Had you toggled your monitor input between VGA and HDMI, you likely would have found Monitor #1 (where all your windows were opening to).